# Tensorflow "Attempting to use uninitialized value ..." Error when restoring

Tags: python, tensorflow, initialization

I made a RNN model.
After training, I saved it in `tf.Session()` like this.

```
#main.py
...(training)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path = saver.save(sess, "Save data/RNN-model.ckpt")
```

and in 'run.py' I tried to restore saved data.

```
#run.py
...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state('Save data/')
    if ckpt and tf.train.checkpoint_exists(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path):
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    ...(training or testing again)
```

when running, error message raise.

```
FailedPreconditionError : Attempting to use uninitialized value accuracy/total
```

However, when I delete codes concerning to `accuracy` in 'run.py' as Error message said, it seems like it's working well I think.

Am I missing something?
Any comments or answers would help me.

thanks.

Comment: Try initializing all global variables and then restoring from the saver for a quick fix.

Comment: @Aaron !!! It works!! `tf.global_variables_initializer` doesn't work. But `tf.local_variables_initializer` does. Thank you, Aaron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `accuracy` operation contains some local variable which is not part of the graph, so it should be initialized manually.
adding `sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())` after`restore` will initialize the local variables.